# How to create chart in MS Excel for unique key sequence?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data something like below,

### data set #1

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
A 10
B 20
C 30
A 50
B 60
C 70
```

It is not properly row-column formatted, so the generated chart is not as expected.

[image]

I know it will be easier if it is formatted like below.

### data set #2

```
A 1 10 50
B 2 20 60
C 3 30 70
```

[image]

But how to generate a line chart for my data set #1 that should look similar to data set #2's chart?

[I have a huge set of data, it can't be transformed by hand]

Comment: Can you transform the data on the spreadsheet before you generate the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: pivotchart]
here I explain how to make a pivot chart of your data, as suggested by @Riverside

- lets label your data: put "label" in cell A2, "value" in cell B2
- in your table, go to cell C3 and type the following formula: `=COUNTIF($A$3:A3,A3)`
- drag the bottom right corner to auto-fill the rest of the rows. Lets call this column:"order" (put in cell C2)
- now select cells A2:C11 and click on: insert -> pivot table -> pivot chart. Under "Choose where you want the PivotTable.." select the radio button which says: "Existing worksheet" and put E2 in the box. click ok.
- in the pivot table Field list pannel on the right drag the "label" field from the top panel into "legend fields", "order" into "axis fields" and "value" into "values".
- on the top left of the ribbon, click "change chart type" and select "line"
- you can close the pivot table dialog boxes and style your chart as normal.
- if you wish to hide the pivot table data, you can simply hide the columns it is in (select columns , right click, hide)

Answer (score 1):

The data would have to be transformed to get a chart like data-set #2. For transformation you could either use pivot tables like @Riverside mentioned, or you could use some simple formulas. Check out [this excel](http://www.4shared.com/file/A8XSTNOXba/ABC.html) which does what you are trying to do.

All you have to do is paste your data, however large it may be, in the first two columns (A and B), and the data is instantly transformed into the 2D set. I've already defined a chart, so you only have to redefine the chart ranges by dragging.

In case the link for the file doesn't work, use [this link (Dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/orkhltpajlpe3qj/ABC.xlsx?dl=1). Note that if you view it on dropbox itself, some formulae don't work, so I'd suggest downloading and viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Put two labels on top of your data.

Then select all data, select insert Line chart in your excel.

Excel automatic see your labels as labels and the rest as data. Your line chart should be fine now.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My problem is with data set #1. Actually, it takes each labels as different one and in the chart, there are 9 lables.

Comment: In that case, the only option I see is to make a pivottable first of your data, and later make a chart of this.